# MailAddress checking

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation

Hi Im trying to check if my email is valid or not,
and wanted to add a restriction that invalidates an email if the @ is followed by a period (.)

I have made/use some of this restriction but I want to add more restriction to it. I need your help on how to declare it.

Cheers

```
private bool IsValidEmail(string email)
    {

        MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress(email);

        var hostParts = mailAddress.Host.Split('.');
        if (hostParts.Length == 1)
            return false; // No dot.
        if (hostParts.Any(p => p == string.Empty))
            return false; // Double dot.

        if (mailAddress.User.Contains(' '))
            return false;
        if (mailAddress.User.Split('.').Any(p => p == string.Empty))
            return false; // Double dot or dot at end of user part.

        return true;

    }
```

this is my code so far

Comment: `string.Contains ("@.")`

Comment: Not sure of your use case, but there is an EmailAddressAttribute which validates the email address. If possible for your project you can use that. OR you can get some ideas on validating it from the source code: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs

Comment: I will have a go and try these stuff and thank you for the quick response

Comment: Validate mailboxes using regular expressions. Example code: "Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-
          9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z ]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
          RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Singleline);
          Console.WriteLine($"The email is {email}");
          bool isValidEmail = regex.IsMatch(email);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to validate anything is to know the syntax.

Here you can find the Syntax of an E-Mail Adress: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax)